# leave and extract pattern r

Tags: r, dataframe, text, substring

I have big data frame, which contains ontology terms, I would likde to substract them and leave there only the word normal and abnormal. The code for generating data is:
`a<-c(" MP:0000266 abnormal morphology; MP:0008725 enlarged heart atrium", "MP:0002169 normal")`
`b<-c("MP:0002165 normal", "MP:0002369 normal")`
`t<-cbind.data.frame(a,b)`
these data should look like

`aa<-("abnormal", "normal")`
`bb<-("normal", "normal" )`
`t<-cbind.data.frame(aa,bb)`
Thanks for your response.

Vendula

Comment: `library(stringr); output = str_extract(input, pattern = "abnormal|normal")`

Comment: Just a note. It's easier and better to create a toy data.frame in one go like this: `t <- data.frame(aa=c("abnormal", "normal"), bb=c("normal", "normal"))`. This way you can mix data.types across your vectors (numeric and character [converted to factor], etc). Also, you don't have a bunch of junk sitting in your environment like the independent aa and bb vectors.